# Tkinter - Canvas.move() doesn't move the last item in the list

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, move

I'm trying to write a Snake Game program using Tkinter
My snake consists of List of Circle's defined below. However, when i call the move method the last one doesn't move. What is the problem?

```
    class Circle:

   def __init__(self,canv,x,y,index,direc):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._index = index
        self._direction = direc
        self._canvas = canv
        coordinat = (self._x)-5,(self._y)-5,(self._x)+5,(self._y)+5

        if index==0:
            color = "gold"
        else:
            color = "green"

        self._circle = canv.create_oval(coordinat ,fill=color, tags=str(self._index))

   def _move(self):
      if self._direction == "up":
         delta = (0,-5)
      elif self._direction == "down":
         delta = (0,5)
      elif self._direction == "left":
         delta = (-5,0)
      elif self._direction == "right":
         delta = (5,0)

      tag = str(self._index)
      self._canvas.move(tag, delta[0],delta[1])
```

and her is how i call it

```
self._canvas = Canvas(self._playArea,width=750,height=450,bg="#1C1C1C")
    x = int(self._parent.winfo_width() / 4.)
    y = int(self._parent.winfo_height()/ 4.)
    circle = Circle(self._canvas,x,y,0,"right")
    self._circleList.append(circle)
    self._addCircle()
    self._addCircle()
    self._addCircle()
    self._addCircle()
    self._addCircle()

    self._canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

    for i in range(0,500):
       for x in self._circleList:
          x._move()
          root.update()
          root.after(10)
```

and this is the addCircle method

```
length = len(self._circleList)
    if self._circleList[length-1]._direction == "right":
        x = (self._circleList[length-1]._x)-10
        y = self._circleList[length-1]._y
        d = "right"
    elif self._circleList[length-1]._direction == "left":
        x = (self._circleList[length-1]._x) + 10
        y = self._circleList[length-1]._y
        d = "left"
    elif self._circleList[length-1]._direction == "up":
        x = self._circleList[length-1]._x
        y = (self._circleList[length-1]._y)+10
        d = "up"
    elif self._circleList[length-1]._direction == "down":
        x = self._circleList[length-1]._x
        y = (self._circleList[length-1]._y)-10
        d = "down"

    newCircle = Circle(self._canvas,x,y,length,d)
    self._circleList.append(newCircle)
```

Comment: Never call `update`. Also, if you change your code listing to be self-contained, then someone might look at it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating the first item with `index=0`, and then using that `index` as the tag to identify the item. You are not supposed to use integers as tags, that is reserved for the id of the items, but, well, you can use it after all. Except that `0` is evaluated as false by Tcl, so you are not effectively defining any tags for it. It turns out you that when you call `canvas.move(0, ...)` you don't move any of the created circles. But the next item you create is assigned a tag "1", and when you call `canvas.move(1, ...)` you are actually moving the item you created earlier (the one with "gold" color) because it was automatically assigned the id "1" by Tcl. Repeat for all the other circles created.

The quick way to solve it is by changing the code to use `index + 1` for all these indices you are passing. But there are several issues in the code you included, so here is a modified one that performs what you are after:

```
import Tkinter

UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT = range(4)

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, canv, x, y, direc, color):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.direction = direc

        self._canvas = canv
        coord = (self.x)-5, (self.y)-5, (self.x)+5, (self.y)+5
        self._index = canv.create_oval(coord, fill=color)

    def move(self):
        y_sign = 1 if self.direction == DOWN else -1
        x_sign = 1 if self.direction == RIGHT else -1
        if self.direction in (UP, DOWN):
            delta = (0, y_sign * 5)
        else:
            delta = (x_sign * 5, 0)
        self._canvas.move(self._index, delta[0], delta[1])


def add_circle(canvas, l):
    d = l[-1].direction
    if d in (UP, DOWN):
        x = l[-1].x
        y = (1 if d == UP else -1) * 10 + l[-1].y
    else:
        x = (1 if d == LEFT else -1) * 10 + l[-1].x
        y = l[-1].y

    circle = Circle(canvas, x, y, d, "green")
    l.append(circle)


def move_circles(circle_l, root):
    for c in circle_l:
        c.move()
    root.after(50, lambda: move_circles(circle_l, root))

root = Tkinter.Tk()
width, height = 750, 450

canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(width=width, height=height, bg="#1C1C1C")
canvas.pack(fill=None, expand=False)

circle_l = []
circle = Circle(canvas, width / 4, height / 4, RIGHT, "gold")
circle_l.append(circle)
for _ in range(5):
    add_circle(canvas, circle_l)

move_circles(circle_l, root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for your help. when i raplaced str(index) with str(index+1) problem is solved. The code that i posted here is just a test case not final one. I'm trying to learn how Tkinter works. I will change it a lot Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but you can make your last piece of code a lot shorter / more efficient:

```
length = len(self._circleList)
    x = self._circleList[length-1]._x
    y = self._circleList[length-1]._y
    d = self._circleList[length-1]._direction

    if d == "right":
        x -= 10
    elif d == "left":
        x += 10
    elif d == "up":
        y += 10
    elif d == "down":
        y -= 10

    newCircle = Circle(self._canvas,x,y,length,d)
    self._circleList.append(newCircle)
```

Set defaults first, then only modify the `x` or `y` if they have to be.